# error performing wfs-t insert in postgres 9.1.4

Tags: openlayers-2, postgresql, postgis-2.0, wfs-t

I am getting **error performing insert** exception while performing wfs-t insert operation when i use **postgres 9.1.4 and postgis 2.0**. but i get **successful insert** when using **postgres 9.0.1 and postgis 1.5**(on another computer). is this some kind of bug in postgres/postgis or i am doing something wrong ?

my script is below

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost= "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
//variables
//var host = "http://192.168.10.11";
var host = "http://localhost";
var port = ':8888';
var centerX = 85.3403;//491213.721224323//-123.1684986291807;//9497800;
var centerY = 27.70774;//5456645.24607268//49.245339757767844;//3212000;
var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(centerX, centerY);
var range = 1.5;//10000000//.5;//10000;
var map_bound = [centerX-range,centerY-range,centerX+range,centerY+range];
var map_wd = 490;
var map_ht = 360;
var legend_wd = 100;
var legend_ht = map_ht;
var tbar_wd = map_wd + legend_wd;
var tbar_ht = 100;
var zoom = 15;

var proj_sp = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

var DeleteFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
    initialize: function(layer, options) {
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
        this.layer = layer;
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Feature(
            this, layer, {click: this.clickFeature}
        );
    },
    clickFeature: function(feature) {
        // if feature doesn't have a fid, destroy it
        if(feature.fid == undefined) {
            this.layer.destroyFeatures([feature]);
        } else {
            feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
            this.layer.events.triggerEvent("afterfeaturemodified", 
                {feature: feature});
            feature.renderIntent = "select";
            this.layer.drawFeature(feature);
        }
    },
    setMap: function(map) {
        this.handler.setMap(map);
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.setMap.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.DeleteFeature"
});

function oldBrowser() {
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    var b_version = navigator.appVersion;
    var version = parseFloat(b_version);
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    switch (browser){
        case 'Microsoft Internet Explorer':
            browser = "MSIE";
            version = useragent.substr(useragent.lastIndexOf('MSIE') + 5, 3);
            if(version<10)
                return true;
            break;
        case 'Netscape':
            if (useragent.lastIndexOf('Chrome/') > 0) {
                browser = "Chrome";
                version = useragent.substr(useragent.lastIndexOf('Chrome/') + 7, 10);
            }
            else if (useragent.lastIndexOf('Firefox/') > 0) {
                browser = "Firefox";
                version = useragent.substr(useragent.lastIndexOf('Firefox/') + 8, 5);
            }
            else if (useragent.lastIndexOf('Safari/') > 0) {
                browser = "Safari";
                version = useragent.substr(useragent.lastIndexOf('Safari/') + 7, 7);
            }
            else
            { alert("undefined browser"); }
            break;
        case 'Opera':
            version = useragent.substr(useragent.lastIndexOf('Version/') + 8, 5);
            break;
    }
}

Ext.onReady(function() {    
    if(oldBrowser()){
        alert("Your browser version is pretty old."
             +"please update to latest version"
             +"performance may be reduced.");
    }

    var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();
    /*saveStrategy.events.register("start", '', alert('saving'));
    saveStrategy.events.register("success", '', alert('save success'));
    saveStrategy.events.register("failure", '', alert('save failure'));
    */
    //map configuration
    var map_options = {
        allOverlays:true,
        maxExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds(map_bound[0],map_bound[1],map_bound[2],map_bound[3]),
        numZoomLevels: zoom,
        controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
        ],
        minScale: 50000,
        projection: "EPSG:4326"
    }
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map(map_options);
    var navi = new OpenLayers.Control.NavigationHistory();
    map.addControl(navi);
    center.transform(proj_sp, map.getProjectionObject());
    //layers configuration
    var world = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "OpenLayers WMS"
        ,"http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wms"
        ,{layers: 'nurc:Arc_Sample'}
        ,{displayInLayerSwitcher:false}
    );

    var roadswgs = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "roadswgs"
        ,host+port+"/geoserver/wms"
        ,{  layers: "postgis:trans_ln_8"
            ,transparent: true
        }
        //,{'reproject': true}
    );

    var portwgs = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "airportwgs"
        ,host+port+"/geoserver/wms"
        ,{  layers: "postgis:airport_runway"
            ,transparent : true
        }
        //,{'reproject': true}
    );

    //var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('editable');

    var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('editable'
        ,{  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),saveStrategy]
            ,protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:  host+port+"/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "airport_runway",
                featureNS: "http://geoserver/postgis",
                version: "1.1.0",
                geometryName: "geom"
            })
            /*,styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                pointRadius: 5,
                strokeColor: "#ff005b",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.4,
                fillColor: '#ffffff'
            })*/
        }
    );
    alert('vector.protocol.url='+vector.protocol.url);
    var wfsroads = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("PostgisWFS", 
        {   strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:  host+port+"/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "trans_ln_8",
                featureNS: "http://geoserver/postgis",
                version: "1.1.0"                    
            })
            /*,styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                pointRadius: 6,
                strokeColor: "#ff005b",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0
            })*/
        }
    );
    map.addLayers([wfsroads,roadswgs,vector,portwgs/*world,,gsat*/]);       
    //adding OSM layer
    //map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM"));
    //adding google satellite layer
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Satellite",{type:G_SATELLITE_MAP, numZoomLevels: 22}));



    //mappanel configuration
    var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        renderTo: 'gxmap',
        height: map_ht,
        width: map_wd,
        map: map,
        title: 'A Simple GeoExt Map',
        extent: map_bound,
        center: center,
        //zoom: zoom
    });
    //layer tree configuration
    var layerList = new GeoExt.tree.LayerContainer({
        text: 'All Layers',
        layerStore: mapPanel.layers,
        leaf: true,
        expanded: true
    });

    var layerTree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        title: 'Layers',
        renderTo: 'layerTree',
        root: layerList,
        width: legend_wd,
        //height: '*',
        autoheight: true
    });

    //legend configuration
    var legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
        title:'Legend',
        layerStore: mapPanel.layers,
        renderTo: "legend",
        border: true,
        width: legend_wd,
        //height: legend_ht,
        autoheight: true
    });

    //editor tools
    var editor = "editor tools";
    { //snap for drawing 
    var snaproad = new OpenLayers.Control.Snapping({
        layer: vector,
        targets: [{
            layer: wfsroads,
            tolerance: 15,
            greedy: true
        }]
    });
    //snaproad.activate();
    var snapvector = new OpenLayers.Control.Snapping({
        layer: vector,
        targets: [{
            layer: vector,
            tolerance: 15,
            greedy: true
        }]
    });
    snapvector.activate();}
    { //Draw Feature control
    var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
        vector,     //layer
        OpenLayers.Handler.Path, //Handler
        {   multi:true,
            type: OpenLayers.Control.TYPE_TOGGLE,
            //handlerOptions : {maxVertices: 5}
        }//options
    );

    /*draw.featureAdded = function(feature) {
        //feature.layer.eraseFeatures([feature]);
        // cast to multilinestring
        //alert(feature.geometry);
        //feature.geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiLineString(feature.geometry);
        //alert(feature.geometry);//feature.style.strokeColor = "#ff0000";
        feature.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;
        feature.layer.drawFeature(feature);
    }*/
    map.addControl(draw);
    // DrawFeature control, a "toggle" control
    var draw_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "draw",
        control: draw,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "draw feature",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });}
    { //Select Feature control
    var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
        vector,
        {multiple: false, hover: true,
        }
    );
    var select_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "select",
        control: select,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "modify feature",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });
    }
    { //Modify Feature control
    var modify = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vector,{type: OpenLayers.Control.TYPE_TOGGLE});
    map.addControl(modify);
    var modify_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "modify",
        control: modify,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "modify feature",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });
    }
    { //Delete Feature control
    var del = new DeleteFeature(vector, {title: "Delete Feature"});
    map.addControl(del);
    var del_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "delete",
        control: del,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "delete feature",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });
    }
    { //Save Feature control
    var save_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "save",
        //icon: 'icons/icon_zoomnext.png',
        //control: saveStrategy.save(),
        onClick: function(){
            //var s=confirm('save?');
            //if(s==true){
                saveStrategy.save();
            //  alert('saved');
            //} 
            //else
            //  alert('not saved');
        },
        disabled: false,
        //deactivateOnDisable: true,
        //activateOnEnable: true,
        tooltip: "save road"
    });}
    { //Measure Feature control
    var length = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
        eventListeners: {
            measure: function(evt) {
                alert("The length was " + evt.measure + ' ' + evt.units);
            }
        }
    });
    var area = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
        eventListeners: {
            measure: function(evt) {
                alert("The area was " + evt.measure + ' sq ' + evt.units);
            }
        }
    });
    var measu_length = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "measu_length",
        icon: 'icons/icon_ruler.gif',
        control: length,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "measu_length",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });
    var measu_area = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "measu_area",
        icon: 'icons/tool_measurearea.png',
        control: area,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "measu_area",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });}
    { //identify Feature control
    var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: host+port+'/geoserver/wms', 
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });
    var identify_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "identify",
        icon: 'icons/icon_query.gif',
        control: info,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "identify",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });}
    { //pan Feature control
    var pan = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan();
    var pan_ac = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "pan",
        icon: 'icons/tool_pan.gif',control: pan,
        map: map,
        // button options
        enableToggle: true,
        tooltip: "pan map",
        toggleGroup: editor
    });
    }
    {//tools simple
    var toolsbar = "tools"          //tools toolbar
    //zoom to max extent tool
    var maxext = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "Max Extent",       
        icon: 'icons/icon_fullextent.gif',
        control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent(),
        map: map,
        deactivateOnDisable: true,
        activateOnEnable: true,
        tooltip: "zoom to max extent"
    });

    var zoomin = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "Zoom In",
        icon: 'icons/icon_zoomin.gif',
        control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomIn(),
        map: map,
        deactivateOnDisable: true,
        activateOnEnable: true,
        tooltip: "zoom inside",
    });

    var zoomout = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "Zoom Out",
        icon: 'icons/icon_zoomout.gif',
        control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomOut(),
        map: map,
        deactivateOnDisable: true,
        activateOnEnable:true,
        tooltip: "zoom outside",
    });

    var pan = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "Pan",
        control: new OpenLayers.Control.Pan(),
        map: map,
        deactivateOnDisable: true,
        activateOnEnable:true,
        tooltip: "drag to move",
    });

    var prev_ext = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "previous",
        icon: 'icons/icon_zoomprevious.png',
        control: navi.previous,
        disabled: false,
        deactivateOnDisable: true,
        activateOnEnable: true,
        tooltip: "previous in history",
    });

    var next_ext = new GeoExt.Action({
        //text: "next",
        icon: 'icons/icon_zoomnext.png',
        control: navi.next,
        disabled: false,
        deactivateOnDisable: true,
        activateOnEnable: true,
        tooltip: "next in history"
    });

    }
    var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({                 //embed tool in toolbar
        renderTo: 'tools',
        width: tbar_wd,
        height: tbar_ht,
        autoWidth : true,
        autoHeight : true,
        items: [draw_ac,'-',modify_ac,'-',del_ac,'-',save_ac,'-',measu_length,'-',measu_area,'-',select_ac,'-',identify_ac,'-',pan_ac,maxext,'',zoomin,'',zoomout,'',prev_ext,'',next_ext]
    });

    // the part below is just to make the bounds show up on the page
    function updateBounds(){
        var bbox = map.getExtent().toArray();
        code = "Bounds      lower left: "+bbox[0]+','+bbox[1]+"     upper right"+bbox[2]+','+bbox[3];
        document.getElementById('bounds').innerHTML = code;
    }
    // update the bounds with each map move
    map.events.register('moveend', map, updateBounds);
    // and update the bounds on first load
    updateBounds();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with Geoserver, neither OpenLayers nor postgresql.

- Which version of Geoserver are you using? (to use postgis 2.0 you should use at least the 2.1.3)
- What is the error generated by geoserver? (you can find it using Firebug, a firefox add-on to inspect the response of the WFS ajax request)

Possibile problems could be

- Old geoserver
- Invalid geometry, maybe you are saving the feature with a different SRID from the one defined in the postgis table

Comment: i am using geoserver 2.1.4 and the geometry is also valid (just a simple line and srid is also correct), the error i get is error inserting feature

Comment: Mmh, could you check the geoserver log file?

Comment: PostGIS 1.5 allow to call some functions without the "ST_" prefix, while 2.0 and up it's required. Mapserver suffer this too.

Comment: There is the possibility to import in postgis 2.x the legacy functions [see the faq](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#legacy_faq)